# How can I take only value from my array objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to get only id from array objects.
this is my array

```
   let profil = [
    { id: '1', name:'John', gender'new-22', age:23},
    { id: '2', name:'Doe', gender'new-33', age:23}
    ]
```

I am trying to get only id value from array objects. my expectation is

```
  [1, 2]
```

and i have tried like this

```
result= profil.filter((item) => item.id);
```

and i got this

```
[ 
0:{id: 1}
1:{id: 2}
]
```

Comment: Use `.map` instead of `.filter`.

Comment: Use `map` instead of filter `result= profil.map((item) => item.id);`